# Prove that one integral implies another integral

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration

Suppose that $f,g$ are differentiable on $[0,e]$ and that $f',g'$ are integrable on $[0,e]$

If $$\int_1^e \frac{f(x)}{x}\, dx \lt f(e)$$

then $$\int_1^e f'(x) \log(x)\, dx \gt 0$$

My attempt

$$\int_1^e f(x) x^{-1}\,dx$$

using integration by parts

$u= f(x), \:du=f'(x),\: dv=\dfrac{1}{x}\,dx,\: v= \log(x)$

which gives

$$f(x)\log(x)-\int_1^e f'(x)\log(x)\,dx$$

I feel like I am close

Comment: The hypothesis is not clear. If $\int_1^e\frac{f(x)}{x}dx$... what? Also, what is the role of the function $g$?

Comment: Your $f(x) \log(x)$ term needs to be evaluated at endpoints...remember this is a definite integral.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since these are definite integrals,$$\int_1^e\frac{f(x)dx}{x}=\color{limegreen}{[f(x)\ln x]_1^e}-\int_1^ef^\prime(x)\ln xdx=f(e)-\int_1^ef^\prime(x)\ln xdx>0.$$

Answer (score 2):

You did it well by integration by parts I guess. Just write your calculations a little bit properly:

\begin{align}
f(e) > & \ \int_{1}^{e} \frac{f(x)}{x} \, \mathrm dx \\
= & \ f(x)\log x \bigg\vert_{1}^{e} - \int_{1}^{e} f'(x) \log x \, \mathrm dx \\
= & \ f(e) \log e - f(1) \log 1 - \int_{1}^{e} f'(x) \log x \, \mathrm dx \\
= & \ f(e) - \int_{1}^{e} f'(x) \log x \, \mathrm dx \\
& \hspace{-2cm}\Rightarrow f(e) > f(e) - \int_{1}^{e} f'(x) \log x \, \mathrm dx \\
& \hspace{-2cm}\Rightarrow \int_{1}^{e} f'(x) \log x \, \mathrm dx > 0
\end{align}